# pgfplots contour lua with data in external file

Tags: pgfplots, lua, contour

i am working on a lot of measured data stored in a file, which i want to visualize with a contour plot. There I have coordinates x and y and a value z as function of x and y, which should be used to calculate the contour lines. Since i am already working with lualatex in Texstudio and pgfplots supports calculating contour lines since version 1.18 I would like to use this feature and not have to install gnuplots.

In this example there are just 9 lines, but in reality there are about a few thousand lines, so i really would like to keep the data in an external file and not have to copy into my texfile.

```
% data.dat
% 
% xColumn,yColumn,zColumn <--- first line
% 0,0,3
% -2,2,1
% -1,-1,2
% 2,2,1
% 1,-1,2
% -1,1,2
% 2,-2,1
% 1,1,2
% -2,-2,1
% 2,-2,1
%             <- last line
```

I tried to create an MWE, but even fail at this step. What I have right now ist the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,compat=newest} 

\begin{document}
    
    
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
        
        \addplot3[contour lua={levels={1,2,3}}] table[x=xColumn,y=yColumn,z=zColumn, col sep=comma] {data.dat};
        
        
        
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Every time I try to compile the document I get the error even though I added a blank line at the end of my data.dat file.

> ! Package pgfplots Error: Sorry, processing the input stream did not lead to en d-of-scanline markers; the generated temporary file for
> 'contour external' does  not contain any of them (indicating that
> matrix structure is lost). To fix thi s, you have the following
> options:
>
> - Insert end-of-scanline markers into your input data (i.e. empty lines),
> - provide two of the three options 'mesh/rows=, mesh/cols=, mesh/num points='.
>
> See the pgfplots package documentation for explanation. Type  H
>   for immediate help.  ...
>
> ```
>                                                l.11 ...Column,z=zColumn, col sep=comma] {data.dat};
> ```

I also tried usising the keys mesh/row and mesh/col or als an alternative mesh/num points, but even with that I still get errors.

Could please someone be so kind and help me out? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either your contour plot is a `prepared contour` where the data has a `\point meta` value - unless it is a `matlab` format where equal `z` is used like this:

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{filecontents}{data.dat}
 xColumn,yColumn,zColumn
0,0,3
-2,2,1
-1,-1,2
2,2,1
1,-1,2
-1,1,2
2,-2,1
1,1,2
-2,-2,1
2,-2,1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[contour prepared format=matlab] table[x=xColumn,y=yColumn,z=zColumn, col sep=comma] {data.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: Graph with several crossing lines]

*or* you will be able to make a `surface` plot first(You do not have to, but you must be able to). To make a surface plot, you data needs to be formated like this:

```
<x1> <y1> <z>
<x1> <y2> <z>
<x1> <y3> <z>

<x2> <y1> <z>
<x2> <y2> <z>
<x2> <y3> <z>
```

With e.g.

```
\addplot3[surf] table {data.dat};
```

**Edit:**

Random example (I have removed commas and header just for ease)

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{filecontents}{data_test.dat}
0 0 3
0 2 1
0 3 2

1 0 1
1 2 2
1 3 2

2 0 1
2 2 2
2 3 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[surf] table {data_test.dat};
\addplot3[contour lua={levels={1,2,3}}] table {data_test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: 3D surface with contours]

Comment: Thank you very much!! It works like a charm. :D