# Why does this MWE not compile (heatmap with contour lines)?

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, luatex, compiling, plot

I'm trying to plot some 3D data which is saved in a csv file.
Plotting just the color map works fine, but I also need to add the contour lines, so I get a result similar to this:

[image: desired result]

My intuition was that it's possible to simply add another `\addplot3[...] table {...}` block to my existing plot like this:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \begin{axis}[...]
    \addplot3[surf] table {data.csv}; % <- this is my existing plot, which works
    \addplot3[...] table {data.csv}; % <- this should be okay?!
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/619309/pgfplots-contour-lua-with-data-in-external-file) seems to be about the exact same issue, so I tried to adapt the answer into my document, but to no avail.

In the end I found that even this minimal example doesn't compile for me (which is the accepted answer from the mentioned question):

```
\documentclass[border=1 cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest} 
\begin{filecontents}{data_test.dat}
0 0 3
0 2 1
0 3 2

1 0 1
1 2 2
1 3 2

2 0 1
2 2 2
2 3 1
\end{filecontents}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}%[view={0}{90}]
\addplot3[surf] table {data_test.dat};
\addplot3[contour lua={levels={1,2,3}}] table {data_test.dat};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

When I try to compile this in my TeXworks installation with the `LuaLaTeX` engine (using the option `--shell-escape`) I get the following error :

```
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/contour lua', to which you
passed 'levels={1,2,3}', and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
```

This error message looks quite similar to the kind of errors I had with my original document, but why do I get it even in this MWE?

Since the OP of the mentioned question has the exact same requirements as I do, I'm confident that my problem is solved once I'm able to compile the MWE above.

Thanks for spending your time!

**Edit:** I just checked for updates in the MiKTeX Console and updated all suggested packages - nothing changed.
I also included `\listfiles` at the top of my document, which returned:

```
 *File List*
standalone.cls    2018/03/26 v1.3a Class to compile TeX sub-files standalone
shellesc.sty    2019/11/08 v1.0c unified shell escape interface for LaTeX
ifluatex.sty    2019/10/25 v1.5 ifluatex legacy package. Use iftex instead.
   iftex.sty    2020/03/06 v1.0d TeX engine tests
 xkeyval.sty    2020/11/20 v2.8 package option processing (HA)
 xkeyval.tex    2014/12/03 v2.7a key=value parser (HA)
standalone.cfg    2018/03/26 v1.3a Default configuration file for 'standalone' 
class
 article.cls    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX document class
  size10.clo    2020/04/10 v1.4m Standard LaTeX file (size option)
luatex85.sty    2016/06/15 v1.4 pdftex aliases for luatex
pdftexcmds.sty    2020-06-27 v0.33 Utility functions of pdfTeX for LuaTeX (HO)
infwarerr.sty    2019/12/03 v1.5 Providing info/warning/error messages (HO)
 ltxcmds.sty    2020-05-10 v1.25 LaTeX kernel commands for general use (HO)
pgfplots.sty    2020/02/29 v1.17 Data Visualization (1.17)
graphicx.sty    2020/09/09 v1.2b Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
graphics.sty    2020/08/30 v1.4c Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)
    trig.sty    2016/01/03 v1.10 sin cos tan (DPC)
graphics.cfg    2016/06/04 v1.11 sample graphics configuration
  luatex.def    2020/10/05 v1.2a Graphics/color driver for luatex
    tikz.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
     pgf.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
  pgfrcs.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
pgfrcs.code.tex
 pgfcore.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
  pgfsys.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
pgfsys.code.tex
pgfsyssoftpath.code.tex    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
pgfsysprotocol.code.tex    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
  xcolor.sty    2016/05/11 v2.12 LaTeX color extensions (UK)
   color.cfg    2016/01/02 v1.6 sample color configuration
pgfcore.code.tex
pgfcomp-version-0-65.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
pgfcomp-version-1-18.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
  pgffor.sty    2020/12/01 v3.1.7a (3.1.7a)
 pgfkeys.sty    
pgfkeys.code.tex
 pgfmath.sty    
pgfmath.code.tex
pgffor.code.tex
tikz.code.tex
l3backend-luatex.def    2020-09-24 L3 backend support: PDF output (LuaTeX)
  ts1cmr.fd    2019/12/16 v2.5j Standard LaTeX font definitions
supp-pdf.mkii
epstopdf-base.sty    2020-01-24 v2.11 Base part for package epstopdf
epstopdf-sys.cfg    2021/03/18 v2.0 Configuration of epstopdf for MiKTeX
 ***********
```

Comment: you have quite old files, stanalone.cls should be 2022 not 2018,  tikz.sty should be 2023-01-15 for example

Comment: standard miktex response to all issues: did you update _both_ user and admin modes?

Comment: I was also wondering about those old versions, because I just updated via the MiKTeX Console. Maybe I should have restartet the editor after updating.
However, it seems I found the issue myself: GNUPLOT wasn't added to PATH...

Comment: miktex has much newer versions, you have not updated it correctly, you updated admin mode and are using user, or the other way round, use the miktex console to update both.

Comment: I might just do a complete reinstall, I haven't done anything in Latex in a quite a while. But for now I'm just happy I finally found the solution.Anyhow, thanks for delving in!

Answer (score 0):

**This answer solved my initial problem involving Gnuplot, not the actual MWE that I posted.**

In the end, the answer was quite simple once you understood what it was all about:

Gnuplot does not refer to a Latex package in this context, but to the external software Gnuplot.
This must be installed separately from the Latex environment, the Latex package manager does not take care of it.
It is crucial that Gnuplot is added to the environment variable PATH!

The corresponding check mark is not set by default when Gnuplot is installed (version 5.5)!

After installation, the command `gnuplot` must be executable in the Windows terminal, otherwise it was not added to PATH correctly and will therefore not be found by LuaLaTeX.

Comment: does that really give a `I do not know the key '/tikz/contour lua',` error? rather than a gnuplot not found error? Your mwe doesn't use gnuplot at all

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I was initially using gnuplot, but found this MWE producing the same errors, so I decided to post it. That makes this answer, which was the solution to my initial problem somehow unsuitable... "Luckily" I'm able to reproduce my issue again: after I thought I understood what was going on I felt confident enough to do a complete reinstall of MiKTeX and gnuplot. I'm completely puzzled now and putting together a proper MWE this time...